# JUnit Parameterized Tests Processing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, parameterized

I have a question about parameterized tests in JUnit. I am running a test suite with all of my test classes, it is a requirement for my course to have a test suite to run all of my test classes, so I cannot modify that. The issue is that I have a bunch of Entry objects (let's just take this as an object with a unique id starting from 1 and incremented every time a new instance of it is created), and they are being pre-processed by JUnit. On compiling and running my program, I have 9 entries which are declared in the `ParamTest` class. Within another class (`EntryTest`) I have one Entry that I have created and it should have an ID of one. However, it has an ID of 10, meaning the 9 entries from the parameterized test class have been created before hand.

My question is, is there anyway to force the `ParamTest` class not to do any of the pre-processing before the `EntryTest` class is run or is this impossible. In the suite I have made sure to declare `EntryTest` before `ParamTest`. If it's impossible is there anyway I can get around this other than creating separate suites or running the tests separately? I was thinking a public static int to keep track of the ID from the pre-processed amounts but it sounds like an ugly solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your testing is going to get ugly, fast, unless you have a way of resetting your static class to a known state.

I would recommend you expose a package-private method that allows you to reset the ID value to something specific (e.g. `0`).

Tests should be entirely independent of one another, even within the same test class.